# kendoui grid cell editor of dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datagridcolumn

I created a KendoUI grid where the first column uses a custom editor. After editing, it doesn't call request of update, however if it is not using editor it will call request of update. Why?

```
var columns = [
    { field: 'AccountId', title: '客户名称', locked: false, template: '#= me.detail.brandName(data, \'ID\') #', editor: accountGridEditor, width: 200 },
    { field: 'BankNo', title: '付款银行', template: '#= me.detail.format(data, \'Bank\') #', attributes: { style: 'text-align: left;' }, width: 150 },                            
    { field: 'UnLinkedAmount', title: '未分配', template: '#= me.detail.format(data, \'UnLinkedAmount\') #', attributes: { style: 'text-align: left;' }, width: 100 },
    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
    ];


var dataSource = c.dataSourceOption({
    transport: {
    read: { url: url.api('Finance/FundJournal') },
    update: { url: url.api('Finance/FundJournal', { action: 'post' }) },
    destroy: { url: url.api('Finance/FundJournal', { action: 'delete' }), type: 'delete' },
    parameterMap: function (data, type) {
        console.log(type);
        console.log(data);
        if (type === 'read') return getReadParameters();
        if (type === "update") return data;
        if (type === 'create') return data;
        if (type === 'destroy') return { id: data.Id };
        return data;
    }
},
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
        AccountId: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
        BankNo: { editable: false},
        UnLinkedAmount: { editable: false }
    }
                            }
},
filter: [{ field: 'SubType', operator: 'neq', value: 'Id' }]

});

    var grid = $("#result").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    height: 550,
    columns: columns,
    editable: "inline",
    save:function(e){$.ajax();}
}).data('kendoGrid');
```

Comment: need to see editor. But it seems that edited record is not marked as dirty after updating with custom

Comment: Yes you are right.finally I add save event configuration in grid

Comment: Glad to help. would appreciate if you accept answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If record property is set from dropdownlist something like this:

```
change: function() {
    options.model.Name = this.value();
    options.model.dirty = true;
}
```

it is necessary explicitly to set that model as dirty, to say to datasource that this record was modified and need to be updated. Otherwise, you can use `set()`.

```
change: function() {
    options.model.set('Name',this.value());
}
```

That way record is automatically marked as dirty in datasource.